# Calculating month-number in python

Tags: python

For example, we have

```
date = 29
number_of_week = 52
year = 2012
```

How to calculate month`s number? 12 in this example. Thanks

Comment: A little more detail regarding what you want to do from this would help us advise you better

Comment: Hmm, seems like he wants to calculate a month given a day of the month, week number (which can vary...), and a year.  Since the definition of a week can vary, you should be more explicit.

Comment: Interesting to note: `datetime.strptime('29 52 2012', '%d %U %Y')` fails miserably with the result: `datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 29, 0, 0)`

Comment: Ah, from the docs: When used with the strptime() method, %U and %W are only used in calculations when the day of the week and the year are specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

def get_month(year, week, day):
    january_first = date(year, 1, 1)
    monday_date = january_first + timedelta(days=week * 7 - january_first.weekday())

    for d in range(7):
        weekday_date = monday_date + timedelta(days=d)
        if weekday_date.day == day:
            return weekday_date.month
```

At this point it's pretty obvious you need better design. What's the bigger picture? Why do you need all this?

Comment: I cant understand how it works) I havnt so much experiance in python, but I try to understand. Thanks